vue 3 composition api, can not return value from a helper function to component
i think this is a problem of scope inside my helper function, i have successfully implementing the same logic in my component and it works perfectly
i have already using a composable function to use ref() with the variable that i want to return
=> this is the working code inside my component
// component.vue
setup() {
    const subnavDiv = ref(false) // this is the variable that the bellow code update

    onMounted(() => {
      const routEl = document.querySelector('.main')
      const fixedNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav')
      const el = document.querySelector('.search')

      let prevYPosition = 0
      let directionVar = 'up'
      const options = {
        root: routEl,
        rootMargin: `${fixedNav.offsetHeight * -1}px`,
        threshold: 0.7
      }

      const setScrollDirection = () => {
        if (routEl.scrollTop > prevYPosition) {
          directionVar = 'down'
        } else {
          directionVar = 'up'
        }
        prevYPosition = routEl.scrollTop
      }

      const onIntersection = ([e]) => {
        setScrollDirection()
        if ((directionVar === 'down' && e.boundingClientRect.top > 0) || !e.isIntersecting) {
          console.log('down')
          subnavDiv.value = true
        } else {
          subnavDiv.value = false
        }
        if (
          e.isIntersecting &&
          (e.boundingClientRect.top < fixedNav.offsetHeight ||
            e.boundingClientRect.top > fixedNav.offsetHeight)
        ) {
          subnavDiv.value = false
        }
      }

      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, options)
      observer.observe(el)
    })

    return {
      subnavDiv
    }
  }
}
}

=> after moving the same code out of the component
// component.vue
setup() {
    const subnavDiv = ref(false)

    onMounted(() => {
      const rootEl = document.querySelector('.main')
      const fixedNav = document.querySelector('.main-nav')
      const el = document.querySelector('.search')

      subnavDiv.value = onIntersect(rootEl, 0.7, fixedNav, el) // the helper function call: this line is supposed to update the value of subnavDiv
    })
})


///////////////////////  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$  ///////////////

onIntersect.js // the helper function
const onIntersect = (rootElement, thresholdValue, elementToChange, elementToWatch) => {
  let prevYPosition = 0
  let directionVar = 'up'
  const options = {
    root: rootElement,
    rootMargin: `${elementToChange.offsetHeight * -1}px`,
    threshold: thresholdValue
  }
  let bool = false // this is the variable that i am trying to return from this function

  const setScrollDirection = () => {
    if (rootElement.scrollTop > prevYPosition) {
      directionVar = 'down'
    } else {
      directionVar = 'up'
    }
    prevYPosition = rootElement.scrollTop
  }

  const onIntersection = ([e]) => {
    setScrollDirection()
    if ((directionVar === 'down' && e.boundingClientRect.top > 0) || !e.isIntersecting) {
      console.log('down')
      bool = true
    } else {
      bool = false
    }
    if (
      e.isIntersecting &&
      (e.boundingClientRect.top < elementToChange.offsetHeight ||
        e.boundingClientRect.top > elementToChange.offsetHeight)
    ) {
      bool = false
    }
  }

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, options)
  observer.observe(elementToWatch)

  return bool // the return (not returning any thing)
}

export default onIntersect


The important part is the ref, the purpose of the ref pattern is to pass a value by reference between scopes. onIntersect is supposed to be a composable and follow regular conventions for them. It's supposed to be called in setup rather than lifecycle hooks.
Direct DOM access is not desirable in Vue. If main, etc are created in the same components, they should be template refs, otherwise they can be provided to the composable as refs, so it could make use of reactivity. The use of onMounted inside a composable would make it inflexible and prone to race conditions. Considering that elementToWatch needs to be accessed first, it could be:
const useIntersect = (rootElRef, threshold, changedElRef, watchedElRef) => {
  const bool = ref(false);
  let observer;

  watchEffect(() => {
    const rootEl = unref(rootElRef);
    const changedEl = unref(changedElRef)
    const watchedEl = unref(watchedElRef);

    if (rootEl && watchedEl) {
      ...
      observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersection, options)
      observer.observe(watchedEl)
    }

    return () => {
      // clean up
      observer?.disconnect();
    }
  });

  return bool;
};

DOM elements can still be accessed directly if necessary, but they are refs any way:
...
const rootElRef = ref(null);
const isSubnav = useIntersect(rootElRef, ...);
onMounted(() => {
  rootElRef.value = document.querySelector('.main');
  ...

As a side effect, it can react to the changes in parameters, e.g. it can be forced to recreate an observer if the options need to be changed.

thank you for your response. but it is impossible to get values of refs outside the onMounted hook. so your suggestions wont work, and this is why i am using helper function instead of composable function so that i can call it inside the onMounted hook

Then it would be like the last snippet shows. Your case isn't unique, problems like these are solved with composables all the time

in the last snippet you can't access to the updated value of ref inside onMounted hook, so you can't call the composable function outside the onMounted hook. thank you again for your reply

Can you clarify what you mean? rootElRef, changedElRef, watchedElRef hold references to elements that aren't available in setup body but are available in mounted hook, that's where you assign the values as soon as they are available. And the observer won't start until all elements are available. The last snippet is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the first snippet in the question. In case this doesn't work for you for some reason, can you provide a workable demo so it could be fixed?

this is a workable demo: link.  all i want is to create a reusable function so that i can use it everywhere in my project. thank you

Good, thanks. This is how it's intended to work with minimal changes for names and ref usage, https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/peaceful-goodall-4fxtgr . If it's possible to access "main", etc template refs directly instead of querySelector like in this example this would be a better design, but any way will work

thank you very much, but there a small problem; codesandbox says, It's likely that the Sandbox you're trying to access doesn't exist or you don't have the required permissions to access it. please check permissions my be it's not public

I updated, check it

I do not know how to thank you, it works perfectly thank you for your support

You're welcome.
